# Why does the HoughLinesP output a 3D array, instead of a 2D array?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy, hough-transform, opencv3.1

I was working with the function (Python, Numpy, OpenCV3) over an image, and this is the sample output I have -

```
[[[539 340 897 538]]

 [[533 340 877 538]]

 [[280 460 346 410]]

 [[292 462 353 411]]

 [[540 343 798 492]]]
```

Its size is (5,1,4)

I am trying to understand what scenario will the function output something like (5,2,4) or (5,3,4). But I can't think of any and all the images I have worked with right now, it's a 3D array with the number of columns as 1.

Wouldn't just a 2D array be sufficient and perhaps more efficient?

Comment: because in openCV the first two dimensions are the matrix and the third dimension is the element's dimension. So typically all 1D outputs in openCV are Nx1 2D matrices. with another dimension for the element type (for example 1d for grayscale pixel values or float distance values, 2D for point coordinates, 3D for rgb values, 4D for point pairs or rgba values, etc.) so the Nx1 part is because of optimization for images, which are 2D matrices with m-D pixels in each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked on the OpenCV Q&A and got the following response -

> opencv is a c++ library, and the python wrappers are auto-generated
> from some scripts, so in c++ we have:
>
> vector lines; to hold the hough results.
>
> now unfortunately , Vec4i is a descendant of Matx , which is actually
> a 2d thing, so in python you get:
>
> [ #one for the vector
>
> [ #one for the 1st dim of Vec4i (1, pretty
> useless, admittedly :)
>
> [ #one for the 2nd dim of Vec4i (4 elements)
>
> again, i think, you'll just have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the extra dimension and since it is 1, just use squeeze

```
>>> a = np.arange(5*4).reshape(5,1,4)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19]]])
>>> a.squeeze()
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Sometimes the extra axis comes in handy

```
a.swapaxes(1,2)
array([[[ 0],
        [ 1],
        [ 2],
        [ 3]],
     ... Snip
       [[16],
        [17],
        [18],
        [19]]])
```

in light of the update and assuming the first is needed either of these return the same results assuming the extra dimension isn't needed.

```
>>> a[0].squeeze()
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a.squeeze()[0]
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful. But I am still wondering why it's 3D to begin with. Any idea on why it wasn't implemented to output a 2D array at all?

Comment: I don't know what it does specifically, but I have come across this before when an extra dimension of 1 is output like (1,5,4)